# How to create buttons on pressing a button?

Tags: java, android

I am using following code to create buttons in a horizontal layout using array of button names:

```
 LinearLayout tabView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabView);
        tabView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);  //Can also be done in xml by android:orientation="vertical"
            for (int i = 0; i < tabButtonNames.length; i++) {
                Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                btnTag.setText(tabButtonNames[i]);
                btnTag.setWidth(50);
                btnTag.setHeight(14);
                btnTag.setTextSize(8);
                btnTag.setId(i);
                btnTag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        ---the code TODO
                });
                tabView.addView(btnTag);
            }
```

They are created but I cannot change the height and the width of the buttons using `setWidth`, `setHeight` or `LayoutParam`. Then on pressing a button, I want to create a list of more buttons in my vertical layout using an array of button names. I used the same code as above in `onClick` method, but application crashes on pressing button. Also `Button btn=new Button(this)` cannot be used in onClick.
I have done this in i-Pad app easily,but here I am having trouble.

Comment: Use  Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());

Comment: pls post your full related code and logcat errors..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
```

OR

`Button btn = new Button(ActivityName.this);`

instead of

```
 Button btn = new Button(this);
```

As Button requires context. And in OnClick, context of Activity is not accessible.

Comment: What if I want to use a method of my own? am i bound to use clickListener?

Comment: if you want it to be added on Click of button . You need to implement Click Listener

Answer (score 1):

`Button btn=new Button(this)` is actually referring your clicklistiner, you have to refer your `class, Button btn=new Button(classname.this)`  or create a simple function outside clickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the context in new Button() and set layout params instead of height and width

```
   for (int i = 0; i < tabButtonNames.length; i++) {
                Button btnTag = new Button(<-Context->);//You need to pass context just write <ActivityName>.this
                btnTag.setText(tabButtonNames[i]);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(<width>,<height>);(50,40)


                //btnTag.setWidth(50);
                //btnTag.setHeight(14);
                btnTag.setTextSize(8);
                btnTag.setId(i);
                btnTag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        }



                });
                tabView.addView(btnTag);
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(params)
}
```